# What is the order of the group ${\rm Aut} (\Bbb Z/p \times \Bbb Z/p)?$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I know that ${\rm Aut} (\Bbb Z/p \times \Bbb Z/p)$ is $2\times 2$ invertible matrix with all possible entries mod $p$. I was asked to count how many elements in this group, but it gets complicated as I tried to count by dividing into several cases. How can I go about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's wrong with this argument for finding Aut($\mathbb{Z_p} \times \mathbb{Z_p}$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511706/whats-wrong-with-this-argument-for-finding-aut-mathbbz-p-times-mathbbz-p)

Comment: It's not so complicated: $p^2-1$ possibilities for the first row, then $p^2-p$ for the second row, giving $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ altogether.

Comment: Awesome... thank you